# libvirt getCapabilities hang if eth is down

Tags: python, unix, virtualization, libvirt

I am creating connection with libvirt

```
>>> import libvirt
>>> conn = libvirt.openAuth("qemu+tls://my-hypervisor/system?no_tty=1")
```

After this I am trying to get the capabilities with function `getCapabilities`.

```
>>> conn.getCapabilities()
```

Its working fine.

But if `eth` interface is down then it hangs on `getCapabilities`.

to reproduce this please connect then down the `eth`.

```
>>> import libvirt
>>> conn = libvirt.openAuth("qemu+tls://my-hypervisor/system?no_tty=1")
```

down the `eth0` on hyperviser machine.

```
[root@my-hypervisor] ifconfig eth0 down
```

now try

```
>>> conn.getCapabilities()
```

Is there any function by which I can test before `getCapabilities` for the connection is alive or not.

Comment: Why do you suggest that traffic to localhost would go through eth0? There's a lo0 for that, isn't it?

Comment: I am trying to connect to another machine but for testing I put url with localhost. I am trying to connect to `eth1` of the hyperviser.

Comment: your question would be better off having non-localhost URIs